# How to determine whether postgres uses huge_pages

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5, huge-pages

I use PostgreSQL 9.5 and have set default value for huge_pages = try. How can I determine if postgres is using it while server is running?

Comment: `grep ^HugePages /proc/meminfo && sudo grep huge /proc/*/numa_maps` - you can determine does the huge pages used at all and which processes used them.

Comment: It seems there is no way to get this info inside PostgreSQL (I am checking in v14) `show huge_pages` returns "try", `show huge_page_size` would be your best bet, but usually it returns 0 because it uses system default. When I use `huge_pages` I set the parameter to `on` in my `postgresql.conf` and I check if `grep ^HugePages_Rsvd /proc/meminfo` is more than 0.

Answer (score -5):

_pages (enum)
Enables/disables the use of huge memory pages. Valid values are try (the default), on, and off.

At present, this feature is supported only on Linux. The setting is ignored on other systems when set to try.

The use of huge pages results in smaller page tables and less CPU time spent on memory management, increasing performance. For more details, see Section 17.4.4.

With huge_pages set to try, the server will try to use huge pages, but fall back to using normal allocation if that fails. With on, failure to use huge pages will prevent the server from starting up. With off, huge pages will not be used.

Comment: it's copied straight from documentation and that's not an answer to my question